# Python magic method for default comparison representation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a class that I want to write custom comparison functions for, is there a way to define the "what" that's being compared instead of writing them out individually?

```
class Version:
    def __init__(self, major, minor, patch):
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
        self.patch = patch

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self.major, self.minor, self.patch

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.version == other.version

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.version > other.version

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.version < other.version
```

Something like,

```
class Version:
    def __init__(self, major, minor, patch):
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
        self.patch = patch

    def __representation__(self):
        return self.major, self.minor, self.patch
```

...which would use that `__representation__` for all the comparison-like operators?

Comment: That doesn't exist, but it sounds like it could be a pretty handy decorator to write.

Comment: @blakev you can look into python `attrs` library . here you go https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2016/08/attrs.html

Comment: You might want to add your support to https://bugs.python.org/issue20632

Comment: @anekix thanks for the recommendation, I was hoping there was something built in.

Comment: note that you'll also have to define `__ne__`

Comment: @blakev if you want something built-in go for python `data classes` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/ . its stdlib alternative for `attrs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to define all in one go. However python provides the [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator that requires you to write only the `__eq__` and one of the comparison magic methods and then add all the others.

Example:

```
@total_ordering
class Version:
    def __init__(self, major, minor, patch):
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
        self.patch = patch

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self.major, self.minor, self.patch

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.version == other.version

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.version < other.version
```

Comment: Probbly the closest possible thing today. Thanks